# why is last-child not working in this example?

Tags: jquery, html, css

In this example, the li:last-child definition comes after the nth-of-type definition, but for some reason the element is styled with the definition that appears first instead of the one that appears last. What's the reason for this? (the last child should be showing up as blue)

HTML:

```
<ul></ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
   var $ul = $('ul');
   var $console = $('div.console'); 

    for( var i = 0; i < 15; i++ ){
      $ul.append('<li>'
        + 'Latest Download ' + (i + 1)
        + '</li>'
     )

     if( ! ((i + 1) % 5) ){
       $ul.append('<div>clear div</div>');   
     }



    }
});
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: lightblue;

    border: 1px solid blue;

    color: green;
    font-family; Arial,Helvetica;
}

ul > li:nth-of-type(5n) {
    color: yellow;
}

ul > li:first-child {
    color: red;
}

ul > li:last-child {
    color: blue;
}
```

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eQRgw/1/

Comment: ul should not have div as a child

Comment: If you remove the last div, it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `li` element is not the last child, the `div` is the last child of the `ul` element so [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child) will match only the last `div` element

use [last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-of-type)

```
ul > li:last-of-type {
    color: blue;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jk9hc/)

Note: `ul` should not have `div` as a child

Comment: thank you for the answer - what would be the better way of accomplishing what i'm currently doing with the "clear divs"?